# Curl разный ответ сервера: 200 и 403

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

Пытаюсь разобраться с Curl/ Запускаю след. код:

```
$url = 'https://klosinski.net/ty-tez-mozesz-projektowac-jak-nauczyc-sie-podstaw-grafiki/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_exec($ch);

$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($http_code);
```

С локального компьютера все работает. Ответ сервера: 200. При копировании этого скрипта на сервер отвечает: 403. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Некоторые сайты не отдают контент, если user-agent (имя браузера) пустой

Comment: Добавил curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'); результат тот-же